# How heavy and expensive are batteries and generators on a 737?

Tags: boeing-737, electrical-system, battery

I am currently struggling to find details on generators and batteries. For a B737 or similar, what would the cost and weight (in £ and Kg) of a battery and IDG be? And do lightweight options exist or already used?

Comment: I just Googled "Boeing 737 Battery" and "Boeing 737 Generator" and a ton of useful looking links came up.  How hard have you looked?

Comment: I can't find an accurate value for the unit cost of these components. I can find stats but that is not what I need

Comment: Probably because they don’t sell them retail.

Comment: I know they don't sell them retail, that's why I'm asking here incase someone knows what they're worth.....

Comment: https://skygeek.com/saft-018550-000-nicad-battery.html. Likely you could negotiate a cheaper deal in bulk.